# Blur entire <li> except last word

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, socket.io, dust.js

I've got a socket.IO application, which also saves the data to MongoDB.

I'm trying to find a method that blur's the entire sentence except for the last word.

The code for where the lines will be:

```
{#storylines}
<li>{text}</li>
{/storylines}

<input id="newstoryline" name="newstoryline" class="StoryBoard" type="text" placeholder="" onKeyDown="countChars()" onKeyUp="countChars()"/>
```

Socket.IO:

```
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
  $('#newstoryline').before('<li>' + data + '</li>');
});
```

The application will also send {maxlines} to the template will will include the number of lines left. Basically i'm looking for a way to say:

if {maxlines} > 0 then blur the 'data' except for the last word.

So if the message from the server was "Hello my name is Jim!" i would want to to be " * **** ** Jim!" so the user can only see the word Jim!

I'm using Node.JS/Mongoose/Socket.IO

Would i have to implement some sort of javascript function on the client side to check if {maxlines} > 0 and then apply the blur effec to the lines or would i do something on the server-side?

Currently this is how the server sends information:

```
app.get('/s/:id', function(req, res){
    Story.findOne({ sid: req.params.id }, function(err, story){
            if (err) {
            res.redirect('/')
        }
        else if(story == null) {
            res.redirect('/')
        }
        else{
    res.render('story', {
        title: 'Storifi',
        storytitle: story.title,
        storylines: story.lines,
        lines: story.maxlines,
        storyid: story.sid
            maxlines: story.maxlines   

                });
            }
        });
});
```

Socket.IO (server-side):

```
socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
    // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
    io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
```

Comment: You would have to wrap each line or word with it's own HTML element ( a `<span>` for example). Then have the effect on all emenets except the last one.

Comment: but the data it receives from the server is one long string, is there no way to get javascript to work out the length of the string and then subtract until the last white space and then blur from 0 --> x? or something along those lines?

Comment: You could use JavaScript's [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to separate words...

Comment: Is there anything that i can do with JS/CSS to blur the text after it's been split?

Comment: Yes there is - but I'm not sure about cross browser support.. You can do a search for CSS3 filters.

Comment: I found this for a blur effect `  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);  ` however i'll have to find something that will work for IE, unless the text-shadow example by user1122614 below works cross-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with lix. Wrap the section that you wish to blur with a span tag, and apply style to that tag with css.

```
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
    var dataSplit= data.split(' ');
    var lastWord =   dataSplit.pop();
    var toBlur=  '<span class="blur">' + dataSplit.join(' ') +  '</span>'; 

     $('#newstoryline').before('<li>' + toBlur + lastWord + '</li>');
});
```

-------------------css---------------------------------

```
.blur{
   color: transparent;  
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;  
}
```

Comment: I've tried the above code however it does not seem to update.
When i type "test message" looking at console i get:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object test message has no method 'join'`
Looks like it does not like `data.join(' ')`

Comment: Got this to work by slightly modifying it to  `socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
    var dataSplit = data.split(" ");
    var toBlur = '<span class="blur">' +  dataSplit.pop() +  '</span>'; 

     $('#newstoryline').before('<li>' + dataSplit.join(" ") + toBlur + '</li>');
});` however if i send the message "This is a test message" it blur's the word message rather than the words this is a test

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to do it but i modified to the code to this: `socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
    var dataSplit = data.split(" ");
    var toBlur = dataSplit.pop(); 

     $('#newstoryline').before('<li>' + '<span class="blur">' + dataSplit.join(" ") + '</span>' + ' ' + toBlur + '</li>');
});` which seems to work

Comment: I corrected the mistakes in my answer its dataSplit.Join() not data.join(). I also mistakenly thought you wanted to blur only the last word. your revision appears correct.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!, i would vote on the answer but it says i need 15 rep or more